# How to create dynamic search in mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

I want to create a dynamic search in mongoose from (get the URL in the request).

Here is sample of my url
http://www.localhost:3000/listing?&colour=blue&gender=women

User able to select multiple colour and gender so that the url can like
http://www.localhost:3000/listing?&colour=blue&gender=women&colour=red&gender=men

I have 3 query record in my mongodb with data like

1)    gender : 'male',
      colour  :  'red'

2)   gender : 'women',
     colour  : 'blue'

3)   gender : 'women',
     colour  : 'blue'

```
var productSchema = new Schema ({
        price: String,
        gender: String,
        colour: String,
        item: [{
            name: String,
            slug: String,
            sku: String,
            size : String,
            stock: String,
        }],
        attributes: {
            waterProof : String,
            warranty : String,
            caseMaterial : String,
            movement : String,
            lens : String,
            bandMaterial : String,
            options : String,
            typeOfMovement : String,
        }
    });

var arrayGet = req.query;
var generateQuery ="{";
for (var k in arrayGet){
if (arrayGet.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
   if(k =='gender'){
     var    gender = arrayGet[k];
   }else if(k =='colour'){
     var    colour = arrayGet[k];
   }
}

if (typeof gender !== 'undefined'){
    generateQuery += '{gender : { $in: gender },';
}
if (typeof colour !== 'undefined') {
    generateQuery += '{price : { $in: colour }';
}

generateQuery +="}";

// i get 3 query from mongoDB which is wrong
Product.find(generateQuery, function(err, result) {
   console.log(result);
})

//i get 2 query from mongoDB which is correct
Product.find({gender : { $in: gender },colour : { $in: colour }},function(err,result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

May i know where i did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not merge all queries into one using $or operator?

```
Product.find({
    $or [
        { colour: 'blue', gender: 'women' },
        { colour: 'red', gender: 'men' }
    ]
}, function (err, results) {

});
```

Using http://www.localhost:3000/listing?&colour=blue&gender=women&colour=red&gender=men as an example, your `req.query` should be coming to you as

```
{
    colour: [
        'blue',
        'red'
    ],
    gender: [
        'women',
        'men'
    ]
}
```

I'm assuming the length of colour and gender arrays will be the same, so you can do

```
var query = {};
query.$or = req.query.colour.map(function (colour, i) {
    return {
        colour: colour,
        gender: req.query.gender[i]
    }
});
```

And then do

```
Product.find(query, function (err, results) {

});
```